# array_rand not running again in do-while loop

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, do-while

I have this do-while statement that repeats when the random generated variable is found in the array, however when the do-while statement repeats, the random array does not change. my code looks like this

```
$verifica = true;
        do
        {
            echo "empieza while";
            $rand2[] =  $_arreglo[array_rand($_arreglo)];   
            //echo $rand2[0]['idpregunta'];
            if(in_array($rand2[0]['idpregunta'], $pregresul)){
                     $verifica = true;
                echo $rand2[0]['idpregunta'];
                $rand2[] =  $_arreglo[array_rand($_arreglo)];
                }else{
                 $verifica = false;   
            }

            echo "termina while";
        }while ($verifica == true );

        echo $rand2[0]['idpregunta'];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by **unseting** my `$rand2` variable before the new loop starts. `unset($rand2);`